how to restart killed application
I implemented android foreground service to restart killed application. So my service monitor logs using READ_CALL_LOG permission and if it is found that my application is not running (killed) and should start new Main Activity.
Unfortunately the timer callback function stop to work when application killed - there is no logging anymore.
in process monitor  I see that service is running and even application started but it is not shown in user's desktop.
What could be used for implement auto-restart for killed critical MAUI application?
**
Update
finally I got is working - the problem was, that in Android ver 14 needs to send foreground service type. Below is my background service implementation based on example:
https://github.com/carlfranklin/MAUIAndroidFS/tree/master/Maui%20XAML%20Version/MAUIAndroidFS
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using AndroidX.Core.App;


namespace MauiAppNeverKilled.Platforms.Android;

[Service(Exported = true, ForegroundServiceType = global::Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeSpecialUse)]

internal class MyBackgroundService : Service
{
    Timer timer = null;
    int myId = new object().GetHashCode();
    int BadgeNumber = 0;
    private readonly IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    //HubConnection hubConnection;

    public class LocalBinder : Binder
    {
        public MyBackgroundService GetService()
        {
            return GetService();
        }
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return binder;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent,
        StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        var input = intent.GetStringExtra("inputExtra");

        var notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        notificationIntent.SetAction("USER_TAPPED_NOTIFIACTION");

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        // Increment the BadgeNumber
        BadgeNumber++;

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                MainApplication.ChannelId)
            .SetContentText(input)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.dotnet_bot)
            .SetAutoCancel(false)
            .SetContentTitle("Service Running")
            .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityDefault)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notification.SetNumber(BadgeNumber);

        // build and notify
      
        int sdkVersion = (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.UpsideDownCake)
            // build and notify
            StartForeground(myId, notification.Build(), ForegroundService.TypeSpecialUse);
        else
        {
            StartForeground(myId, notification.Build());
        }
        // timer to with main check if application closed
        timer = new Timer(Timer_Elapsed, notification, 0, 3000);

        // You can stop the service from inside the service by calling StopSelf();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    async void Timer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
        AndroidServiceManager.IsRunning = true;

        
        var activity = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;

        if(activity == null || activity.IsDestroyed || activity.IsFinishing)
        {
            OpenPackage(package);
        }
        


        Log.Info("mauneverkilled", $"bs timer - {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }
    void OpenPackage(string packageName)
    {
        var appScreen = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        appScreen.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront);
        appScreen.SetAction("START_ACTION");

        
        appScreen.PutExtra("packageName", packageName);
        this.StartActivity(appScreen);
    }           
}

And in AndroidManifest.xml
     <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"
   android:minSdkVersion="34" />


Can you add some relevant code?

@SevaAlekseyev a service in a different process will not stop the OS from killing it

You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android. That includes from a foreground service IIRC.

If you're asking about starting foreground service when service is killed , then  use auto start permission in android, https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter -- in this project it has explained about auto start permission
And as per the application one can start mainactivity of their application from service , you just have to check on specific condition that your app is running or not

@CommonsWare I can start activity from foreground once I have SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and get from user ActionManageOverlayPermission
